# GATK documentation for required depth to reliably call heterozygous mutation in diploid organism?

Tags: gatk, wgs, coverage

I'm looking for official GATK documentation (or a recent manuscript) that defines a general recommendation/requirement for sequencing depth to reliably call a heterozygous point mutation in a diploid organism (WGS). In this case, I'm working with humans. Specifically, suppose we're looking at position X in the genome and we want to classify (True/False) whether there was enough coverage to detect a heterozygous point mutation.

What coverage would that be? I'm curious about both: (1) UnifiedGenotyper and (2) HaplotypeCaller

I know general practice is to have 30x coverage genomewide, but I don't see anything in GATK's documentation (i.e., [Best Practices](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/best-practices/)) about required coverage.

Really appreciate your help.

Note: I also submitted a [question to the GATK team](https://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/13003/recommended-required-sequencing-depth-for-standard-diploid-whole-genome-germline-variant-calling/p1?new=1) end of last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As an update, Sarah Walker (co-author on the poster) responded to [my question](https://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/comment/52425#Comment_52425) on the `GATK` forum. She clarified with the following statement:

> We believe the sites around 30X (and above 150X) are being filtered
>   due to low mapping quality (since it is whole genome so there are many
>   areas that are hard to map), which explains the low sensitivities in
>   these areas. As the error bars show, there are very few variants in
>   these low mapping quality areas.

She then posted the following plot that falls much more inline with what we would all expect. This is a plot showing sensitivity for `NA12878` compared to NIST truth.
[image: NA12878: sensitivity by depth]

---

shlee, from the GATK forums, [pointed me](https://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/comment/52425#Comment_52425) to [a poster from AGBT 2018](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XDXlck-El8uZ7e60ANDSHycEpkgo6NoP) where the authors compared the HiSeqX and NovaSeq instruments. Figure 3 shows sensitivity for SNPs and short INDELs across multiple allelic fractions (AF) from spike-ins. ***I was surprised to find that SNPs where AF = 0.4 only had ~50% sensitivity at ~25x coverage, and only ~75% sensitivity at ~50x coverage***.

The poster is targeted at somatic variation, but data from figure 3 should behave like a standard diploid germline variant because you often see a wide range of allelic fractions from germline variants. They used spike-ins for figure 3. It's not clear to me whether they used HaplotypeCaller in figure 3, but I don't see how they could have used Mutect2, like they did in figures 1 & 2.

Based on this information, **it appears the standard 30x genome-wide coverage is generally insufficient to confidently call many heterozygous mutations, and that ~90-100x is ideal.**

**Am I missing something? Are we really missing that many heterozygous mutations in standard WGS/WES?**

I'll leave this question unanswered for now to allow others to chime in on interpretation, etc. I'd appreciate additional thoughts.

[image: poster from AGBT 2018]